# Programmatically Sending Email to Current User

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, sharepoint

I am wanting to send an email to the current user on button click. I have gotten the current user email with this line of code and am storing it in a variable:

```
SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Email
```

But am now looking for the best way to send an email to this user, through Outlook... Can anyone provide me with best practices they have experienced in this field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to send an email programmatically is to use SMTPClient. I have provided an example here:

```
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports System.Net

' You need a MailAddress for both to and from
Dim addresses As MailAddress = New MailAddress("SomeEmail@gmail.com")

' The structure for MailMessage(from, to)
Dim message As MailMessage = New MailMessage(addresses, addresses)

message.Subject = "I have sent you a message from a program!"
message.Body = "Hello World!"

Dim messanger As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)

messanger.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("YourGmailAccount@gmail.com", "YourPassword")
messanger.EnableSsl = True

messanger.Send(message)
```

So the way it works is like this. First you have to identify who is sending the message and receiving the message. As you can see I just made it the same email, which is good for testing purposes, to this:

> "SomeEmail@gmail.com"

Then you have to create the message which will contain your subject line and body. You can insert html code, along with a lot more, into your body but for now keep it simple like this:

```
Dim message As MailMessage = New MailMessage(addresses, addresses)
message.Subject = "I have sent you a message from a program!"
message.Body = "Hello World!"
```

Once you have completed that you need to create the SMTPClient which will send the message to the SMTP server, I used gmail because it is outlined pretty easy how to configure a connection:

```
Dim messanger As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
messanger.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("YourGmailAccount@gmail.com", "YourPassword")
messanger.EnableSsl = True
```

There are a few things to note when configuring your SMTPClient. First you need to use the exact host name, and correct port for the connection to be established. Second, depending on the SMTP server, you may need to provide credentials for the Server to accept your request. Finally, you have to turn on SSL encryption, for gmail messages.

Finally, once you have generated all of the correct items, and associated the correct information you are able to send the message with the SMTPClient like so:

```
messanger.Send(message)
```

Also, you will need these two namespaces for the code to work:

```
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports System.Net
```

Comment: Yes, this can work with Outlook. To use with Outlook you should use the IP address of the Exchange server. The port would be useful, but if you connect by IP, without it, the server should still work properly.

Answer (score -1):

Once you can get the email, in SharePoint, you can use the SharePoint function SPUtility.SendEmail to send the email. More info about the function http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.sendemail.aspx

Also make sure that outgoing e-mail settings are configured properly.